# pass function parameter into ajax url doesnt' work?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

```
    $scope.getPostItem = function(itemLength){
        // load post items ajax
        $http({
            method: 'GET', 
            url: '../Rresume/loadPostItem.php?itemLength=itemLength'}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

});
```

trying to pass itemLength into the url, possible? I got a null result. But when I put itemLength=4 it work.

Comment: In your case you can use the short version: `$.get('../Rresume/loadPostItem.php?itemLength=' + itemLength, function(r) { ... }, 'JSON?').success(function() { ... })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scope.getPostItem = function(itemLength){
        // load post items ajax
        $http({
            method: 'GET', 
            url: '../Rresume/loadPostItem.php?itemLength=' + itemLength}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

});
```

Try this

Comment: In your case it's not using the variable.